# Application of class instance method results in making class instance variable None?

Tags: python

I have a class I've made to hold all information about my data points. Data points are often collected in a series of measurements, so I want to keep them together: hence, `DataPoints` and `LotsOfDataPoints`

```py
#this is simplified code, but reproduces my issue

class DataPoint:    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def add_number(self, number):
        self.value += number
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
        
class LotsOfDataPoints:    
    def __init__ (self, *values):
        self.lst = []      
        for value in values:
            self.lst.append(DataPoint(value))
            
    def add_one(self):
        self.lst = [d.add_number(1) for d in self.lst]
```

I can successfully create a DataPoint:

```py
d = DataPoint(1)
print(d)
> 1

d.add_number(1)
print(d)
> 2
```

I can successfully make LotsOfDataPoints:

```py
ds = LotsOfDataPoints(1,2,3,4,5)
print(ds.lst)
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I can call the DataPoint method on an individual DataPoint

```py
ds.lst[0].add_number(1)
print(ds.lst)
> [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However, when I try to `add_one()` to my LotsOfDataPoints, they all turn to `None`.

```py
ds.add_one()
print(ds.lst)
> [None, None, None, None, None]
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: `DataPoint.add_number()` doesn't return anything; it's therefore pointless to use it in a list comprehension, and if you do so anyway it's useless to assign the resulting list of Nones anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the problem lies here

```
def add_one(self):
    self.lst = [d.add_number(1) for d in self.lst]
```

Your `DataPoint.add_number` method does not return anything, hence the `self.lst` is filled with `None` values. What you actually want to do is

```
def add_one(self):
    for d in self.lst:
        d.add_number(1)
```

This should edit the `DataPoint` objects without emptying the `LotsOfDataPoints.lst` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by returning `self.value` in the function `add_number`. Because, in the loop - `[d.add_number(1) for d in self.lst]`, the function is just being called. The values aren't saved. The modified code is as follows:

```
class DataPoint:    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def add_number(self, number):
        self.value += number
        return self.value
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
        
class LotsOfDataPoints:    
    def __init__ (self, *values):
        self.lst = []      
        for value in values:
            self.lst.append(DataPoint(value))
            
    def add_one(self):
        self.lst = [d.add_number(1) for d in self.lst]
```

The output obtained is as follows:

```
d = DataPoint(1)
print(d)
> 1
```

```
ds = LotsOfDataPoints(1,2,3,4,5)
print(ds.lst)
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
ds.add_one()
print(ds.lst)
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```